# Comparator : How to sort on two parameter when one is instance variable and other is reference in the Same Class

Tags: java, sorting

I have A Country class which has a parameter countryName and List player now I want to sort it on the basis of the country in ascending and run scored by players in descending.

```
class Country {

    private String countryName;
    private List<Player> player;

    public Country(String countryName, List<Player> player) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        Collections.sort(player, new PlayerComparator());
        this.player = player;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(List<Player> player) {
        this.player = player;

    }

}

class Player {

    private String playerName;
    private int runScored;

    public Player(String playerName, int runScored) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.runScored = runScored;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public int getRunScored() {
        return runScored;
    }

    public void setRunScored(int runScored) {
        this.runScored = runScored;
    }

}

class CountryComparator implements Comparator<Country> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
        return o1.getCountryName().compareTo(o2.getCountryName());
    }
}
    class PlayerComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
            if (o1.getRunScored() > o2.getRunScored())
                return -1;
            else if (o1.getRunScored() < o2.getRunScored())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

    }

    // main class

public class MyMain{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player1=new Player("sachin",10000);
        Player player2=new Player("saurav",8000);
        Player player3=new Player("dravid",7000);
        Player player4=new Player("dhoni",7500);
        List<Player> indianList=new ArrayList<>();
        indianList.add(player1);
        indianList.add(player2);
        indianList.add(player3);
        indianList.add(player4);

        Player player5=new Player("ricky",9500);
        Player player6=new Player("gilchrist",8500);
        Player player7=new Player("bevan",9300);
        Player player8=new Player("clark",8700);
        List<Player> ausiesList=new ArrayList<>();
        ausiesList.add(player5);
        ausiesList.add(player6);
        ausiesList.add(player7);
        ausiesList.add(player8);

        Player player9=new Player("peterson",5500);
        Player player10=new Player("daren",2000);
        Player player11=new Player("nashir",6500);
        List<Player> englandList=new ArrayList<>();
        englandList.add(player9);
        englandList.add(player10);
        englandList.add(player11);

        Country country1=new Country("Australia",ausiesList);
        Country country2=new Country("India",indianList);
        Country country3=new Country("England",englandList);

        List<Country> list=new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(country1);
        list.add(country2);
        list.add(country3);

        Collections.sort(list,new CountryComparator());

        list.forEach(country -> {
            System.out.print(country.getCountryName()+"\t");
            country.getPlayer().forEach(player -> {
                System.out.print("\t"+player.getRunScored()+"\t");
            });
            System.out.println();
        });

    }
}
```

I am able to do it but only when I am sorting on players while setting them in country class which is not good OO approach. I want it to be sorted on both the parameter only when I call Collection.sort but not while setting the country class because that way I am changing my country class.

how to sort on both parameter without having to sort Players while setting country name and players in the country class.

Comment: You can sort it whenever needed, what's the problem?

Comment: `I want to sort it on the basis of the country` You basically need to put the country inside `Player` to sort it.  Another way to look at it is *you already have the players sorted by country* because they're each in their own list by country.  Just print out the countries in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sorting when printing, by using streams, leaving the collections unsorted.

```
list.stream().sorted(new CountryComparator()).forEach(country -> {
    System.out.print(country.getCountryName()+"\t");
    country.getPlayer().stream().sorted(new PlayerComparator()).forEach(player -> {
        System.out.print("\t"+player.getRunScored()+"\t");
    });
    System.out.println();
});
```

**UPDATE**

To sort the lists themselves, do this:

```
list.sort(new CountryComparator());
list.forEach(c -> c.getPlayer().sort(new PlayerComparator()));
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for output in the List<Country> which is sorted on both the parameters.

Comment: @neo This is output from the `List<Country>` with both countries and players within the country sorted. What different *output* do you expect?

Comment: your code works fine but i want sorted value in list as i have to pass this sorted List<country>to another method. All i am asking is how can i reuse this sorted output. Can't we reuse stream?

Answer (score 0):

Given the list :

```
List<Player> listOfPlayers = Arrays.asList(new Player("ENG", 10), new Player("FRA", 20), 
                                           new Player("GER", 40), new Player("FRA", 30));
```

You can sort it based on country name and runs scored using the following:

```
Collections.sort(listOfPlayers, new Comparator<Player>() {
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {        
        // if strings are same then compare runs
        if (p1.getPlayerName().compareTo(p2.getPlayerName()) == 0) { 
            return p2.getRunScored() - p1.getRunScored();
        } else {
            // else compare the strings
            return p1.getPlayerName().compareTo(p2.getPlayerName());
        }
    }
});
```

This outputs :

> Player [playerName=ENG, runScored=10]
>
> Player [playerName=FRA, runScored=30]
>
> Player [playerName=FRA, runScored=20]
>
> Player [playerName=GER, runScored=40]

Comment: Actually, I have to Country as different class and Players as a different class. please see my code. It would be of great help if i can get a output in List<Country> sorted on both the parameters

Comment: So you're saying that you want to sort `Country` based on `countryName` and `List<Player>`?

Comment: yes and if possible output should be in List<Country>

Comment: Not really sure of that. Your design is a bit messy - I don't see any reason why Country should have a *list* of players within country itself. Maybe you could use a *TreeSet* instead so as you add the elements, the set would be already sorted(based on the Comparator). However, now, you can make sure that the list of players is sorted as shown above and then all you need to do it use compareTo method for the country name.